# Problem with digits in URLs when using mathspec and hyperref

Tags: fonts, hyperref, mathspec

When I use `mathspec`'s `\setmathsfont` and `hyperref`, and try to typeset a URL, most of the URL uses monospace, as it should. Good.

However, digits use the maths font. Anyone know how to fix this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec,fontspec,hyperref}

\setmathsfont(Digits){Minion Pro}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}

\begin{document}
\nolinkurl{abc123def} % same problem with \url{..}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks for the edit. I didn't have enough reputation to embed the image myself, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `mathspec` makes the digits of type `mathord` not `mathalpha`. Then the work done by hyperref to set up to use the ttfamily does not conclude successfully for the digits, as it proceeds in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec,fontspec,hyperref}

\setmathsfont(Digits){Minion Pro}

\makeatletter
     \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`0}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`1}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`2}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`3}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`4}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`5}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`6}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`7}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`8}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`9}
\makeatother

% \setmonofont{Source Code Pro}

\begin{document}
\nolinkurl{abc123def} % same problem with \url{..}
\end{document}
```

[image: digits in mono]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thankyou so much.

Comment: You're welcome! I looked for an option to `mathspec` package to do this, but there does not seem to be one, so I just copied-pasted from `mathspec.sty` and replaced `\mathord` by `\mathalpha`. The point is that `hyperref` does its things in math mode (after having set-up the font to be the mono font).

Comment: I also ran into this problem. Now I'm wondering, is this a bug? If so, in which package, `hyperref` or `mathspec`?

Comment: @ph0t0nix  The legacy LaTeX setup declares the digits of variable family type (aka "mathalpha") in order to be able to access old style figures via `\mathnormal`: `$\mathnormal{0123456789}$`. Package `mathspec` perhaps decided this did not make sense anymore in the context of Unicode type fonts. As per `hyperref`, well, it can not have to think about all possibilities; perhaps include a note in its documentation. Same can be said of `mathspec`.