# Different font for numbers in URLs

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mathspec

I am using [`mathspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) to make the fonts in math mode match the roman fonts used in my text body. The “digits” environment in `mathspec` takes effect for all digits in the document. This means that digits that would normally use a font other than roman, such as those within URLs, also end up using this font, despite loading the `mathspec` command `\setallmonofonts` (which I had assumed would override `\setmathfont`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){Book Antiqua}
\setallmonofonts{Courier New}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text. Some figures: 123456789\\
\url{http://some.urlwithnumbers/123456789}

$$Some text in math mode. Some figures in math mode: 12345789$$

\end{document}
```

[image: image of xelatex output]

Is there a way of setting the font for only the digits that occur in math mode? I would like to keep my specified monospace font for digits within monospaced strings (and likewise with sans serif fonts, should I need to use them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99774 seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){Arial}
\setallmonofonts{Courier New}

\makeatletter
     \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`0}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`1}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`2}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`3}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`4}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`5}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`6}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`7}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`8}
     \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`9}
\makeatother



\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text. Some figures: 123456789\\
\url{http://some.urlwithnumbers/123456789}

\[Some text in math mode. Some figures in math mode: 12345789\]

\end{document}
```

[image]